# How to find common ArrayList elements?

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to compare two ArrayList (they are not necessarily equal size) and create a new ArrayList that contains all the common elements of list1 and list2. Is there a more efficient way of doing this than comparing all the elements of list1 to all the elements of list2?

Comment: Also, what are your rules for duplicates? I.E. if list1 contains `[a,b,c]` and list2 contains `[a,a,b]` what would list3 contain?

Comment: I've literally just been taking one element of list1 and comparing it to every elements of list2, and then adding it to the commonList if there's a match. @Batty

Comment: @aruisdante, the question made no mention of duplicates so I assume the common list would simply contain it only once

Answer (score 0):

I would say for optimal efficiency just loop over the smaller of the two lists and use the contains method when accessing the longer list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.length(); i++) {
  if(listB.contains(listA.get(i)) {
    commonList.add(listA.get(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: There are definitely non *O(n^2)* ways to do this, especially if duplicates don't need to be accounted for and the output list doesn't need to be stable (same order as input lists).

Answer (score 0):

You could you [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) to do this. What you are looking for is the [CollectionUtils.intersection(Iterable a, Iterable b)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) method.